# ¿como conecto correctamente angular con spring boot usando spring tool 4-4.16?

Tags: java, mysql, angular, spring-boot, spring-tool-suite

amigos desde esta mañana estoy luchando con este error que me devuelve la consola del navegador:

> ERROR HttpErrorResponse {headers: HttpHeaders, status: 404,
> statusText: 'OK', url:
> 'http://localhost:8080/springTest/usuarios', ok: false, …}

He intentado un monton de soluciones añadiendo anotaciones y nada. paso el codigo:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
import { Usuario } from './../modelo/Usuario';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root',
})
export class ServiceService {
  constructor(private http: HttpClient) {}

  Url = 'http://localhost:8080/springTest/usuarios';

  getUsuarios() {
    return this.http.get<Usuario[]>(this.Url);
  }
}
```

aqui el codigo del controlador:

```
package com.sinfloo.demo.controlador;

import java.util.List;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.CrossOrigin;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.GetMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;

import com.sinfloo.demo.modelo.*;
import com.sinfloo.demo.interfaceService.*;


@CrossOrigin(origins="http://localhost:4200", maxAge=3600)
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/usuarios")
public class controlador {
    
    @Autowired
    UsuarioService service;
    
    
    @GetMapping
    public List <Usuario>listar(){
        return service.listar();
    }

}
```

y de la clase principal he añadido varias anotaciones dado que me salio otro error que lo coloco al final y con las anotaciones se "solucionaron"

```
package com.sinfloo.demo;

import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.jdbc.DataSourceAutoConfiguration;


@SpringBootApplication(scanBasePackages={
"com.springTest.something", "com.springTest.application"}, 
exclude={DataSourceAutoConfiguration.class})
public class SpringTestApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(SpringTestApplication.class, args);
    }

}
```

package.json

```
{   "name": "test",   "version": "0.0.0",   "scripts": {
    "ng": "ng",
    "start": "ng serve",
    "build": "ng build",
    "watch": "ng build --watch --configuration development",
    "test": "ng test"   },   "private": true,   "dependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "^14.2.0",
    "@angular/common": "^14.2.0",
    "@angular/compiler": "^14.2.0",
    "@angular/core": "^14.2.0",
    "@angular/forms": "^14.2.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "^14.2.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "^14.2.0",
    "@angular/router": "^14.2.0",
    "rxjs": "~7.5.0",
    "tslib": "^2.3.0",
    "zone.js": "~0.11.4"   },   "devDependencies": {
    "@angular-devkit/build-angular": "^14.2.5",
    "@angular/cli": "~14.2.5",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "^14.2.0",
    "@types/jasmine": "~4.0.0",
    "jasmine-core": "~4.3.0",
    "karma": "~6.4.0",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "~3.1.0",
    "karma-coverage": "~2.2.0",
    "karma-jasmine": "~5.1.0",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "~2.0.0",
    "typescript": "~4.7.2"   } }
```

Si le quito esta anotacion(

> scanBasePackages={ "com.springTest.something",
> "com.springTest.application"},

) a la clase principal del proyecto spring boot  sale el siquiente error:

> Field repositorio in com.sinfloo.demo.service.UsuarioServiceImp
> required a bean of type
> 'com.sinfloo.demo.interfaces.UsuarioRepositorio' that could not be
> found.
>
> The injection point has the following annotations:
>
> - @org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)
>
> Action:
>
> Consider defining a bean of type
> 'com.sinfloo.demo.interfaces.UsuarioRepositorio' in your
> configuration.

Porfa alquien que me de una ayuda!!!

añado el archivo application.properties

```
spring.jpa.database=mysql
spring.jpa.show-sql=false
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=update

spring.datasource.driver-class-name=com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver 
 
 spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://localhost/test?useTimezone=true&serverTimezone=UTC
 spring.datasource.username=root
 spring.datasource.password=
 spring.jpa.database-platform=org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5InnoDBDialect
```

spring.datasource.password= esta vacio porque la base de datos por ahora no tiene contraseña

Comment: 404 significa que no encuentra la URL, estás seguro de que tienes configurada la API en spring para que sirva en `localhost:8080/springTest...`?? Porque en el controller solo se ve la parte final `/usuarios`, revisa que tengas bien escrita la ruta en la configuración...

Comment: Soy nuevo en spring boot, toda la documentacion y los tutoriales no indican que se debe añadir el nombre del proyecto en la url desde el proyecto springboot; de todas manera probe desde angular cambiando la url a esto: http://localhost:8080/usuarios y es igual 404.

Comment: Y no tendrás en la configuración una base de ruta en plan `/api` o algo así?? Porque muchos tutoriales también indican eso... Podrías poner el yaml de configuración (sin los valores privados como contraseñas, tokens y demás), sería de ayuda para debugar el problema, que claramente no tiene pinta de ser de Angular, si no de la parte de tu API.

Comment: listo añadi el archivo application.properties

Answer (score 0):

El error es que estás definiendo mal la URL, es por eso que no lo encuentra y te arroja el **error 404**. Esta URL tiene que ser tal cual lo que estás enviando en tu servicio. En tu `@RequestMapping` pon lo siguiente:

```
@RequestMapping("/springTest")
```

Y luego en tu `@GetMapping`:

```
@GetMapping(value = "/usuarios")
```

Comment: Lo he probado y no funciona. En la documentacion que he leido no dice que se deba añadir ningun valor al @GetMapping

Comment: Te sigue saliendo el mismo error? Bueno los @GetMapping los utilizo así para concatenar URL's

Comment: Si lo mismo. No cambia el error

Comment: Yo no sé lo que has leído en la documentación, pero desde luego que es normal añadir valores al getMapping... Si necesitas tener dos `get` en la misma URL por cualquier motivo, debes poder indicar qué ruta toma cada uno! O imaginate que quieres obtener un único objeto, cómo lo haces? Pues `@GetMapping(value = "/{id}")`! Es **muy normal** indicar las rutas en la etiqueta, incluso si es solo un `"/"`, para clarificar exactamente qué ruta corresponde a cada método. Ayuda mucho cuando vas a abrir un controller que no tocas desde hace dos años, simplemente añadirlo a modo de *documentación*

Comment: En los @GetMapping debe ir un valor para especificar que ruta corresponde para cada método que usas... Ésta [pregunta](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50351590/difference-between-path-and-value-attributes-in-requestmapping-annotation) de SO podría ayudarte.